# WCF ria services return list of complex types

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I have a complex type entity

```
public class ComplexEntity : ComplexObject
{
private int _ID;
private string _Name;
private int _ParentID;

[Key]
[DataMember]
public int ID { get;set;}

[DataMember]
public string Name {get;set;}

[DataMember]
public int ParentID {get;set;}

}
```

and another one

```
[DataContract]
public class ComplexEntitiesList : ComplexObject
{
[DataMember]
[Include]
[Association("CEntities_CEntity","ID","ParentID")]
public List<CompelxEntity> List {get;set;}

[Key]
[DataMember]
public int ID {get;set;}

public int LKEntitiesList()
{
List = new List<LKEntity>;
}
```

and a method:

```
[Invoke]
public ComplexEntitiesList GetPS()
{
return new ComplexEntitiesList() { List = /*..some logic*/});
}
```

On the server side everything's perfect however the list comes empty at the client side
Any clues?
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Include will not work wit Invoke-Operations. Take a look at [this](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/160586/360703.aspx) question on silverlight.net and see Colin Blairs answer. Your method GetPs() should return a normal collection (aka. List) containing your complex objects.

```
[Invoke]
public IEnumerable<ComplexEntity> GetPS() {
  return new List<ComplexEntity>() { /*..some logic*/});
}
```